# Can move child in LinearLayout up but not down

Tags: android, android-layout, view

Can someone please explain why the first piece of code here works but not the last piece? The only difference is the index of which i insert my view, `i-1` and `i+1`. Is `i+1` just not possible with index? I can write any other number in there and it works.

```
         upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < drawerViewGroup3.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = drawerViewGroup3.getChildAt(i);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_name);
                    if (tv.getText().toString().equals(drawerName.getText().toString()) && i != 0) {
                        drawerViewGroup3.removeView(view);
                        drawerViewGroup3.addView(view, i - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < drawerViewGroup3.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = drawerViewGroup3.getChildAt(i);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_name);
                    if (tv.getText().toString().equals(drawerName.getText().toString())) {
                        drawerViewGroup3.removeView(view);
                        drawerViewGroup3.addView(view, i + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Some context on the app. I have a vertical oriented `LinearLayout` with multiple `LinearLayouts` inside. When clicking the two `Button`s in the code, one of the children is to move up or down, switching their positions.

EDIT: Ok so I figured it out.

```
            downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View viewToMove = null;
                int viewToMovePos = drawerViewGroup3.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < drawerViewGroup3.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = drawerViewGroup3.getChildAt(i);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_name);
                    if (tv.getText().toString().equals(drawerName.getText().toString()) && i != drawerViewGroup3.getChildCount() - 1) {
                        viewToMovePos = i;
                        viewToMove = view;
                    }
                }
                alert.dismiss();

                if (viewToMovePos != drawerViewGroup3.getChildCount()) {
                    drawerViewGroup3.removeView(viewToMove);
                    drawerViewGroup3.addView(viewToMove, viewToMovePos + 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Not the prettiest code and probably not gonna help others as it's very specific, but that was the answer.

Comment: I suggest that you use a `RecyclerView` instead of `LinearLayout`. It is designed for creating a list of dynamic views.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove a view from your LinearLayout, the view at index `i` is now the view which was **after** the one which you removed. Then you add a view at `i - 1` which is before this view (the one which was previously after the removed view). The final result is that you remove a view and insert back where it used to be.

Instead, you need to add the view at `i - 2`.

I suggest that you look at `RecyclerView`. It is specifically designed to efficiently create a dynamic list of views for given data. You only have to manipulate the data and `RecyclerView` does all the hard work for you.

Comment: Wait but `i - 1` is the one working, `i + 1` does not work, which is why i'm confused. Lets say i have: **a | b | c** then i hit c and click my up button it then becomes **a | c | b** and now i need to be able to hit c again and click my down button so it goes back to **a | b | c**.

And i hadn't heard about `RecyclerView`, but will look into it.

Comment: @Yiha5000 Okay, my details seem to be off. The general principle is to be careful about off-by-one errors because after removing a view, the indices of views from position i and above change.